# ¿Cómo hacer evento de mouse al pasarlo sobre una imagen de un jLabel?

Tags: java, botón, eventos, interfaz-gráfica, cursor

Uso NetBeans 8.1, Me gustaría que cuando pongo el cursor del mouse en la esquina superior derecha, donde está el botón de cerrar se cambiara de color o cambiara de imagen (en este caso la misma imagen de color rojo)
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Te faltaria agregar el codigo para que puedan ayudarte y mostrar bien el error.

Comment: wtf no tiene nada que ver

Comment: que no tiene que ver?

Answer (score 0):

Si es un botón el que debe de reaccionar, debes de añadir un listener a ese botón, si quieres que reaccione al mouse, debes de añadir un mouselistener.

En un foro es imposible enseñar todo el tema de eventos, que es bastante complejo. Si no sabes qué es un evento y como funcionan, mejor busca información sobre ello. Hay video-tutoriales muy buenos en youtube.

Otras respuestas te podrán dar el código exacto que necesitas poner. Pero en ese caso otros te solucionarán la papeleta, no la solucionarás tú.

Comment: Esta no aplica como respuesta, seria un comentario.